# How to detect if a Model property is a foreign key relation? (And retreive all FK Model objects)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to create a table that propagates dynamically with django objects, where each row is a django model object. If the object property is a foreign key, the goal is to display a drop-down list of all the possible FK options. To do this, I'll need to detect if the object field is an FK and then retrieve all FK objects.

There are two components to this:

- I'm struggling to determine if the object property is an FK relationship
- I'm struggling to get all object of the same model as the FK

The idea in pseudocode would be:

```
for field in object.fields:
  if field is FK:
    return field.objects.all()
  else:
    return field
```

I know that I can test for a ForwardManyToOneDescriptor relation (below), but is there a more compact general way to test for a FK relationship?

```
isintance(Foo.bar, db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ForwardManyToOneDescriptor):
```

Is there any way of getting all of the model objects of the FK, either by the model class or an instance of the class?
`Foo.bar.all()` or `Foo.objects.first().bar.all()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating over the object fields, you can access the `_meta` object, and iterate over the fields, like:

```
from django.db import model

[f for f in t._meta.get_fields() if isinstance(f, models.ForeignKey)]
```

You can obtain the model that is referenced with:

```
[f.related_model for f in t._meta.get_fields() if isinstance(f, models.ForeignKey)]
```

You thus can obtain querysets with all objects with:

```
[f.related_model.objects.all() for f in t._meta.get_fields() if isinstance(f, models.ForeignKey)]
```

Comment: Thanks for this! The models.ForeignKey is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately in the last example, `f.model` returns the initial model `Foo`, rather than the FK instance of object `Bar`.

Comment: Looks like the solution for the final would be 'f.related_model.objects.all()'

Comment: @MaxChandler: aarggh, yes. sorry somehow I got confused and swapped the two. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the help! I updated your answer to reflect that.